# Use dates as numbers, but format them as dates in UI

Tags: d3.js, d3fc

Let's take this example.

https://d3fc.io/examples/series-canvas-candlestick/

It defines X scale as a time scale.

```
const xScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain(fc.extentDate().accessors([d => d.date])(data));
```

To prevent multiple tick to date conversion in my zoom handler, I'd like to always work with number, but keep UI showing these numbers as dates. So, I change the code above to linear scale.

```
const xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain(fc.extentLinear().accessors([d => d.date.getTime()])(data));
```

Everything works fine, but now I have an X scale showing numbers instead of dates. The question is, how to add mapper or formatter that would show these numbers as dates in UI? I see some examples of d3.tickFormat, but not sure how to apply it in d3fc.

https://observablehq.com/@d3/axis-ticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You supply your scales to the D3FC cartesian chart, which then couples these with the axes that it creates for you.

As [mentioned in the documentation](https://github.com/d3fc/d3fc/blob/master/packages/d3fc-chart/README.md#cartesian_xTicks) the chart exposes the properties of the X and Y axes with an `x` and `y` prefix. So, if you want to change the tick format for the X axis, which you would typically do via the `tickFormat` property, you instead do the following:

```
var chart = fc.chartCartesian(
    d3.scaleLinear(),
    d3.scaleLinear()
  )
  .xTickFormat(/* ... formatter goes here */);
```